# How do I find the characters common to two strings in Java using single replaceAll?

Tags: java, regex, optimization, string

So suppose I have:

```
String s = "1479K";
String t = "459LP";
```

and I want to return

```
String commonChars = "49";
```

the common characters between the two strings.

Obviously it is possible to do with a standard loop like:

```
String commonChars = "";
for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
{
    char ch = s.charAt(i);
    if (t.indexOf(ch) != -1)
    {
        commonChars = commonChars + ch;
    }
}
```

However I would like to be able to do this in one line using `replaceAll`. This can be done as follows:

```
String commonChars = s.replaceAll("["+s.replaceAll("["+t+"]","")+"]","");
```

My question is: is it possible to do this using a single invocation of `replaceAll`? And what would be the regular expression? I presume I have to use some sort of lookahead, but my brain turns to mush when I even think about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String commonChars = s.replaceAll("[^"+t+"]","");
```

Note that you may need to escape special characters in `t`, e.g. using `Pattern.quote(t)` instead of `t` above.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer:

```
String commonChars = s.replaceAll("[^"+t+"]","");
```

has a bug!!!

What if the string `t` has a regex meta-character? In that case the `replaceAll` fails.

[**See this program**](http://www.ideone.com/dsvjm) as an example where the string `t` has `]` in it and `]` is a regex meta-character which marks the end of the character class. Clearly the program does not produce the expected output.

Why?

Consider:

```
String s = "1479K";
String t = "459LP]";
```

Now the regex will become(just substitute `t`):

```
String commonChars = s.replaceAll("[^459LP]]","");
```

Which says replace any character other than `4`,`5`,`9`,`L`,`P` **followed by a** `]` with nothing. Which is clearly not what you want.

To fix these you need to escape the `]` in `t`. You can do it manually as:

```
String t = "459LP\\]";
```

and the [**regex works fine**](http://www.ideone.com/l6ySq).

This is a common problem when using regex, so the `java.util.regex.Pattern` class provides a static method named [**quote**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) which can be used to do exactly this: quote the regex-metacharacters so that they are treated literally.

So before using `t` in `replaceAll` you quote it as:

```
t = Pattern.quote(t);
```

[**Program using quote method**](http://www.ideone.com/vV0m8) works as expected.

Comment: Does this mean I need to do:
    String commonChars = s.replaceAll("[^"+Pattern.quote(t)+"]","");
instead? Will this still check for each character individually?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is incorrect. Because the `replaceAll` is a Pattern, we must consider the syntax.
What will happen if `s1 = "\\t"` ? And what will happen if `s1 = "]{"` ?

If all chars are in range[0 - 255], we can work like this:

1. `byte[] tmp = new byte[255];`
2. loop each char in first string

   `for (char c : str1.toCharArray())

       // or use charAt(i) here   if (tmp[c] == 0) tmp[c] = 1;`
3. loop each char in second string

   `for (char c : str2.toCharArray())
     if (tmp[c] == 1) tmp[c] = 2;`
4. loop the tmp array, find the members with value of 2,    the index
   is the right char we are look for.

Another solution is using `HashSet.retainAll(Collection<?> c);`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class common {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String s = "FIRST";
      String s1 = "SECOND";
      String common = s.replaceAll("[^" + s1 + "]", "");
      System.out.println(common);
   }
}
```