# Set intersection of two strings

Tags: java, set

```
import java.util.*;

class set {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TreeSet<Character> t1 = new TreeSet<Character>();
        TreeSet<Character> t2 = new TreeSet<Character>();
        String s1 = "Ambitab bachan";
        String s2 = "Ranjikanth";
        for (char c1 : s1.toCharArray())
            t1.add(c1);
        for (char c2 : s2.toCharArray())
            t2.add(c2);
        t2.retainAll(t1);
        System.out.println(t2);
    }
}
```

this program finds the common character in two different strings. In this program `TreeSet` is used to store the value and `retainAll()` method is used to find the common characters.

Can anybody help me reduce the line of code.

Comment: Apart from putting several statements on the same line, it is going to be difficult to reduce the number of lines. In particular, `toCharArray` returns a `char[]` so you need to transform each `char` to `Character` in a loop st some stage.

Comment: Declare two variables in same line? different statements in single line?

Comment: Why are you concerned about reducing the number of lines in code that's clearly not for production? Is it a metric that you're trying to rate with?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library, you can simply use [`Sets.intersection()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#intersection%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29) and avoid the boilerplate.

Comment: am a beginner in java. kindly suggest some idea which help to improve my programming skill in java. thanks in advance. what sort of book i should  buy..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11382820/130224

Answer (score 2):

As you're dealing with Strings, you can forgo all these objects and use regular expressions.

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_DEDUPLICATE = Pattern.compile("(.)(?=.*\\1)");

public void intersect(String string1, String string2) {
    String commonChars = string1.replaceAll("[^" + string2 + "]", "");
    String uniqueCommonChars = REGEX_DEDUPLICATE.matcher(commonChars).replaceAll("");
    return uniqueCommonChars;
}
```

The first `replaceAll` removes all characters from `string1` that are *not* in `string2`. `commonChars` is thus:

```
itaahan
```

More in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203911/how-do-i-find-the-characters-common-to-two-strings-in-java-using-single-replacea).

The second `replaceAll` removes redundant instances of a character, the last two 'a's in this case. `uniqueCommonChars` becomes:

```
ithan
```

A great break down of how this regex works is in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582940/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-characters-and-keep-the-unique-one-only-in-perl).

Compiling regular expressions is *relatively* computationally expensive so the we can precompile one as a `static final Pattern`. As the other regular expression is based on the input, it cannot be precompiled.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could condense this:

```
TreeSet<Character> t1 = new TreeSet<Character>();
for(char c1:s1.toCharArray())
t1.add(c1);
```

Into: (Edited)

```
TreeSet<String> t1 = new TreeSet<String>(Arrays.asList(s1.split("(?<=.)")));
```

Comment: asList will take a `Character[]` but not a `char[]`

Comment: Ah, you're right, and converting to a `Character[]` would make it just as long as the original, by any method that springs to mind.  Thanks.

Comment: All right, this version should work (actually tested to be sure this time).  Ugly though.  Wouldn't recommend actually doing this sort of thing...

Comment: I was thinking `.split("")` but I think that produces an empty string at the start.

Comment: Yes, I had that problem with my first try, but using a lookbehind, as `s1.split("(?<=.)")` solves that problem.

Answer (score 1):

A bit simpler:

```
    TreeSet<Character> t1 = new TreeSet<Character>();
    String s1 = "Ambitab bachan";
    String s2 = "Ranjikanth";
    for(char c1:s1.toCharArray()) {
      if (s2.contains(new Character(c1).toString())) {
        t1.add(c1);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove the duplicate code to build the character sets

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    TreeSet<Character> t1 = asCharacterSet("Ambitab bachan");
    TreeSet<Character> t2 = asCharacterSet("Ranjikanth");
    t2.retainAll(t1);
    System.out.println(t2);
}

private static Set<Character> asCharacterSet(String value) {
    TreeSet<Character> t1 = new TreeSet<Character>();
    for (char c1 : value.toCharArray())
        t1.add(c1);
    return t1;
}
```