# java regular expression with replaceAll on string

Tags: java, regex

I have two strings :

`s = "aaaaaaa"` 
and 
`m = "a"`

I want output as `commonChars="a"` but i am getting `commonChars="aaaaaaa"` and for `s = "a"` `m = "aaaa"`

I want output `commonChars="a"`

Can anyone suggest me regular expression for that  ?

My code is

```
String commonChars = s.replaceAll("[^" + m + "]", "");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
String commonChars = s.replaceAll(m + "+", m);
```

Comment: Thank you..but what if i also want to find the common character in two string like if s = "avfd" m = "av" than output is commonChars="av"

Comment: @JayeshAhir It depends on how you use it. :)

Comment: Basicly i want find common characters in two string ..so can you suggest me regex for that..thanks

Comment: You can't use regular expressions that way. A regular expression is a single expression which matches a number of strings. It can't be used to extract common characters of multiple strings.

Comment: Indeed see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203911/how-do-i-find-the-characters-common-to-two-strings-in-java-using-single-replacea) to see how problematic that can be

Comment: same code i am using for finding common characters but i also want answer that gives me output specified in my question .